MCMC timing parallel vs serial
I am trying to optimize a function that calculates a model that I am fitting with emcee. I profiled it and found the part that was taking the most time, and did a fairly radical re-engineering of that section which makes that function run over twice as fast in my standalone tests.
I.e. the new function, running on its own, is about twice as fast.
When I replace it in the MCMC probability function, however, the timings get weird. I have tested it on my laptop (MacBook Pro 2.4 GHz Quad-Core i5, 16 GB RAM, OS 14.5, Python 3.9.12, Numpy 1.21.5, Scipy 1.7.3) and my desktop (Mac Studio M1 Max w/ 8 performance and 2 efficiency cores, 64 GB RAM, OS 14.5, Python 3.10.9, Numpy 1.26.4, Scipy 1.10.0). I have tested both with multiprocessing and without, and get the following timings:
Old code, laptop: 11.21s/it (serial), 4.57s/it (parallel)
Old code, desktop: 4.83s/it (serial), 1.15s/it (parallel)

These make sense -- the newer CPUs are each faster, and there is a significant parallel speedup. But with the new code, I get the following timings:
New code, laptop: 8.75s/it (serial), 3.02s/it (parallel)
New code, desktop: 2.23s/it (serial), 4.83s/it (parallel)

On the laptop, things make sense -- about 30% speedup in either case. But on the desktop, I see roughly the same speedup with serial but a dramatic slowdown when I run it with multiprocessing!
The bottleneck in the old code was scipy.ndimage.rotate, while the new code takes a very different approach using scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator and index arrays into two different coordinate systems -- now the longest parts are lines that create the index arrays.
The only thing that makes any sense to me is that there's a memory issue, but the desktop has 4x as much memory and about 2x as many cores, so I would expect it to have fewer memory issues, and I'm at a loss of how to troubleshoot better.
I guess my questions are:

Any good ideas of what might be leading to this behaviour?
If not, any suggestions of how to better figure out what's going on?
Any suggestions for fast substitutes for scipy.ndimage.rotate for rotating a 3D array around an arbitrary (non-Cartesian) axis that don't run into memory issues?


"Any good ideas of what might be leading to this behaviour?" Could be a bottleneck in pickling/unpickling. Are the arguments to this function, or the return values from this function, very large arrays? If so, the cost of pickling the array so the child process can work on it can be more expensive than if the parent process executed the function directly.

"Any suggestions for fast substitutes for scipy.ndimage.rotate for rotating around an arbitrary (non-Cartesian) axis that don't run into memory issues?" Are you only doing rotations by multiples of 90 degrees? If yes, there are better options. If you need arbitrary angles, I don't know of a better way.

First thing is profile your application and see where is the bottleneck. It's better than guessing. To check if pickling/unpickling is problem: Try parallel with one worker.

dankal: When I profile the functions on their own, they act like I'd expect, and they don't look different when profiled inside the MCMC.

NO: I rolled my own version that directly calls scipy.ndimage.affine_transform that's actually blazing under all conditions, which I'll submit as an answer for reference.

NO: The function I'm changing only takes very small input/output, though the likelihood function that calls it does take a somewhat larger array (61x61).

In response to point 3, I did end up with a massive speedup by doing the rotation using affine_transform instead of rotate. In particular, I replaced the following code (rotation around the x axis followed by rotation around the z axis):
rot1 = scipy.ndimage.rotate(original, angle1, axes=(1,2), reshape=False, order=1)
final = scipy.ndimage.rotate(rot1, angle2, axes=(0,1), reshape=False, order=1)

with
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

rotvec1 = [np.deg2rad(angle1), 0, 0]
rotvec2 = [0, 0, np.deg2rad(angle2)]
rot = Rotation.from_rotvec(rotvec2) * Rotation.from_rotvec(rotvec1)
centerpt = np.asarray(original.shape)/2 - 0.5
offset = centerpt - centerpt.dot(rot.as_matrix())
final = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(original, rot.as_matrix().T, order=1, offset=offset, output_shape=original.shape, cval=0.)

which is based heavily on this answer: How can I use scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform to rotate an image about its centre?
In parallel on my desktop, it now runs at 12.70it/s, so about 15 times faster than before!
